# What is the relationship between the complete and init events when using the Loader?

Tags: actionscript-3, events, flash

The [documentation for Loader in the Actionscript 3.0 reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html#Loader%28%29) appears to contradict itself.

> - The `complete` event is dispatched when a file completes downloading, but before the loaded movie clip's methods and properties are available.

According to the first point, the `complete` event means that a file has completed downloading.  We're loading a `swf` file and using the `complete` event to signal that it has been loaded.  Yet we are finding that in some circumstances, the resources we are loading are not available to us.  This line in the documentation makes a lot of sense to us as why we are having this problem, and we were planning to switch to using the `init` event instead.

But then the documentation goes on to say:

> - The `init` event is dispatched after the properties and methods of the loaded SWF file are accessible, so you can begin manipulating the loaded SWF file. This event is dispatched before the `complete` handler. In streaming SWF files, the `init` event can occur significantly earlier than the complete event. For most purposes, use the `init` handler.

This also makes sense to us except that it says that the `init` event is dispatched before the `complete` handler.  This doesn't make sense to us, because this seems to contradict itself.  If the `complete` event is dispatched before the loaded movie clip's methods and properties are available, and the `init` event is dispatched after the properties and methods of the loaded SWF file are accessible, then how could the `init` event be dispatched before the `complete` event?

I would love to hear from someone who works with these events more often and can clarify the documentation on this point.  Here are my specific questions about this documentation and process:

- What is the difference between the meanings of the `complete` and `init` events?
- Is it important that the documentation uses the words "event" and "handler" here?  i.e. "This [`init`] event is dispatched before the `complete` handler." Is this telling us to hold off on handling the `complete` event until the `init` event is also dispatched?

The documentation also clearly states, "For most purposes, use the `init` handler."  So at the very least we're expecting to change our software from using `complete` to using `init` instead.  We will probably just wait for both, especially if we see them coming in different orders in our testing.  But I'm still looking for some sanity here.  Hopefully someone can provide this?

Comment: That is odd, well spotted. I think the "but..." in the `complete` description is just a mistake, as I'm fairly sure I've never seen `complete` fire before `init`, and the description of the events themselves (in the Loader.load() section) is more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't event listeners be attached to the Loader's LoaderInfo object?

The Event.COMPLETE [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html#event%3acomplete) says:

> Dispatched when data has loaded successfully. In other words, it is
>   dispatched when all the content has been downloaded and the loading
>   has finished. The **complete** event is always dispatched after the **init**
>   event. The **init** event is dispatched when the object is ready to
>   access, though the content may still be downloading.

The simplified explanation:

- Event.INIT is dispatched when all 'layers' (including code and assets) of the first frame have loaded
- Event.COMPLETE is dispatched when all frames have finished loading.